# log pysvn update

Tags: python, logging, pysvn

How could I, if possible, get information on what files have been added, removed, updated etc when running svn update in pysvn? I want to write this information to a log file.

Answer (score 2):

you can save the original and updated revision, then use diff_summarize getting updated files. (see [pysvn Programmer's reference](http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html))

here's an example:

```
import time
import pysvn

work_path = '.'

client = pysvn.Client()

entry = client.info(work_path)
old_rev = entry.revision.number

revs = client.update(work_path)
new_rev = revs[-1].number
print 'updated from %s to %s.\n' % (old_rev, new_rev)

head = pysvn.Revision(pysvn.opt_revision_kind.number, old_rev)
end = pysvn.Revision(pysvn.opt_revision_kind.number, new_rev)

log_messages = client.log(work_path, revision_start=head, revision_end=end,
        limit=0)
for log in log_messages:
    timestamp = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(log.date))
    print '[%s]\t%s\t%s\n  %s\n' % (log.revision.number, timestamp,
            log.author, log.message)
print

FILE_CHANGE_INFO = {
        pysvn.diff_summarize_kind.normal: ' ',
        pysvn.diff_summarize_kind.modified: 'M',
        pysvn.diff_summarize_kind.delete: 'D',
        pysvn.diff_summarize_kind.added: 'A',
        }

print 'file changed:'
summary = client.diff_summarize(work_path, head, work_path, end)
for info in summary:
    path = info.path
    if info.node_kind == pysvn.node_kind.dir:
        path += '/'
    file_changed = FILE_CHANGE_INFO[info.summarize_kind]
    prop_changed = ' '
    if info.prop_changed:
        prop_changed = 'M'
    print file_changed + prop_changed, path
print
```

Comment: `summary = client.diff_summarize(url,pysvn.Revision(pysvn.opt_revision_kind.committed),url ,pysvn.Revision(pysvn.opt_revision_kind.previous)) ` can diff_summarize be used like above on two url not on the working path?

Answer (score 1):

When you create your client object, add a [notify callback](http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html#pysvn_client_callback_notify). The callback is a function that takes a `dict` of information about the event.

```
import pysvn
import pprint

def notify(event_dict):
    pprint.pprint(event_dict)

client = pysvn.Client()
client.callback_notify = notify

# Perform actions with client
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but there is not an accepted answer and I stumbled across it while searching for info pertaining to `node_kind`.

```
import pysvn

tmpFile = open('your.log', 'w')

repository = sys.argv[1]
transactionId = sys.argv[2]
transaction = pysvn.Transaction(repository, transactionId)

#
#   transaction.changed()
#
#   {
#       u'some.file': ('R', <node_kind.file>, 1, 0),
#       u'another.file': ('R', <node_kind.file>, 1, 0),
#       u'aDirectory/a.file': ('R', <node_kind.file>, 1, 0),
#       u'anotherDirectory': ('A', <node_kind.dir>, 0, 0),
#       u'junk.file': ('D', <node_kind.file>, 0, 0)
#   }
#

for changedFile in transaction.changed():
    tmpFile.writelines(transaction.cat(changedFile))

    # if you need to check data in the .changed() dict...
    # if ('A' or 'R') in transaction.changed()[changedFile][0]
```

I use Transaction in similar ways to the above in an SVN pre-commit hook script.

See documentation for dictionary details:
http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html#pysvn_transaction
http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html#pysvn_transaction_changed

Also, though I did not use Transaction's list() method that may also be of interest:
http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html#pysvn_transaction